# How to excecute a <p:remoteCommand> from javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have a trouble when I try to excecute a remote command from a javascript code, always in the console I have the erro, ReferenceError: notificar is not defined and I don’t know why, this is my code, thanks

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    Hello from Facelets
    <p:growl id="notifyGrowl" widgetVar="notifyGrowl" life="3000" showDetail="true"/>
    <h:form>
        <p:remoteCommand name="notificar" actionListener="#{remoteCommandView.execute}" update="notifyGrowl" />
    </h:form>

</h:body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.WebSocket) {
        var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/SEIPA3/push");

    } else {
        console.log(" Browser doesn't support it");
    }
    ws.onmessage = function (event) {

            notificar();
    };
</script>
```

Comment: as the error says you're calling `notificar()` but it doesn't  exist. Where `notificar` come from?

Comment: sorry, i am new in primefaces, I've been watching examples about how to eject the remoteCommand, and in all examples,they say call the command as if it were a javascript function, but I do not know what I'm doing wrong or what I need to do, thanks for answering

Comment: Your code runs well, can you try this:  use this public websocket wss://echo.websocket.org and capture the event onopen instead onmessage, and put on your remoteCommand oncomplete="alert(ok);"

Comment: If "ok" is shown, the problem can be your websocket

Comment: does not display the alert, when debugging the javascript I can see that the websocket sends the data correctly, my problem is when the javascript wants to execute the remoteCommand in this way notificar(), it tells me that the function does not exist and is correct does not exist, but in other examples I have seen that in this way they execute the remoteCommand from javascript, but I still do not know why it does not work for me. Thank you for your answers

Comment: Why is the javascript outside your `h:body`?

Comment: Guys I solved this problem, what happened was that I ran my application and as I was in the browser, I went to my client directly from the url by typing the address where he is staying, doing an inspection of the source code of the page of the cliene I realize that I was still showing the code of primefaces as such, which is not right, should have been processed and displayed as pure html, so put a button from my index to send me to the client, so that now when doing the inspection showed me the html code already processed, and everything went well. thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I solved this problem, what happened was that I ran my application and as I was in the browser, I went to my client directly from the url by typing the address where he is staying, doing an inspection of the source code of the page of the cliene I realize that I was still showing the code of primefaces as such, which is not right, should have been processed and displayed as pure html, so put a button from my index to send me to the client, so that now when doing the inspection showed me the html code already processed, and everything went well. thanks.